# Does google Analytics also count visitors from Bing, Yahoo and Yandex?

Tags: google-analytics

Does google Analytics (Audience Overview) also count sessions from Bing, Yahoo and Yandex ?

Answer (score 3):

Yes it does count those visitors as well. To help you better understand how they are categorized, visits are sorted into:

**3 Basic Traffic Mediums**

The Google Analytics Traffic Sources section categorizes your site traffic as

- Direct traffic
- Referring traffic
- Search engine traffic

[image]

**Direct traffic.** represents those visitors that arrive directly and immediate on your site by:

1. Typing your URL into the browser’s address bar
2. Clicking on a bookmark
3. Clicking on a link in an email, SMS, or chat message

Direct traffic is a strong indicator of your brand strength and your success in email or text message marketing.

Direct traffic can also be an indicator of offline marketing success.

**Referring traffic.** Referring site traffic, which is sometimes called referrer traffic or referral traffic, counts those visitors that click a link on another site and land on your site. Referral traffic can be indicative of social media marketing success.

**Search engine traffic.** Search engine traffic is that traffic that comes from visitors clicking on links on a search results page for any search engine — whether Google, Bing, Yahoo!, Blekko, or similar. This traffic source is divided into organic or non-paid search engine traffic — meaning that the visitor clicked on a so-called natural search result — and CPC or paid search engine traffic, which is the traffic you purchase (via pay-per-click ads_ from search engines. Search engine traffic usually indicates that you have good or at least reasonably good content. It also can mean that you have chosen a good software platform. Be sure to learn which keywords are driving this traffic. Multi-channel merchants, as an example, may find that their brand name is a key search term. When this is the case, offline marketing is usually the real traffic driver.